# list large number of s3 bucket objects to out file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a large number of files in an s3 bucket (10m) and I would like to write out these files to a text file for further processing.

the question is how do I efficiently do this? is:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname > out.txt
```

the only option? I only need the file url however. How can one achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with that command?

Comment: maybe this can help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html

Comment: @Paolo it gives me a bunch of things like timestamps, I just want to filter out the filename

Comment: You could use something like `aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket example-bucket --query "Contents[].[Key]" --output text` to just get a list of keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [S3 inventory report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html)? You still need some post-processing to give you the desired format though.

Answer (score 0):

Write a python shell job and get the list of folders and file names from the S3.
The following python job gets you the Folder and its file names and then write the CSV file to another S3 location.

```
import sys
import os
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
import boto3

# Specify the S3 bucket and path
s3_bucket = "your_source_bucket"
specific_file = ""  #only needed in case you want for a specific folder or file

# Create an S3 client
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# List objects in the bucket with pagination
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=s3_bucket,Prefix=specific_file)

# Extract folder names and file names
folder_names = set()
file_names = []

for response in response_iterator:
    for content in response.get('Contents', []):
        key = content['Key']
        if '/' in key:
            folder_name, file_name = os.path.split(key)
            folder_names.add(folder_name)
            file_names.append((folder_name, file_name))
        else:
            file_names.append(('', key))


# Save the list of file names to a CSV file
csv_output_path = "/tmp/s3_files.csv"  # Use a local temporary file
with open(csv_output_path, 'w') as file:
    file.write('Folder,File\n')
    for folder_name, file_name in file_names:
        file.write('{},{}\n'.format(folder_name, file_name))

# Upload the CSV file to S3
s3_client.upload_file(csv_output_path, "your_bucket", "your_prefix_and_file_name")

# Clean up the temporary file
os.remove(csv_output_path)
```